# How to get the average of a group every 9 years

Tags: pandas, average, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame called EPI. 
it looks like this:

[image]

It has 104 countries. Each country has values from 1991 till 2008 (18 years).
I want to have average every 9 years. So, each country will have 2 averages.

An edit: 
This is the command I used to use it to get average. But it gives me one value (average) for each country.

```
aver_economic_growth <- aggregate( HDI_growth_rate[,3], list(economic_growth$cname), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But I need to get an average for each 9 years of a country.

Please note that I am a new user of r and I didn't find pandas in packages installment!

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can first convert years to datetime and then `groupby` with `resample` `mean`. Last convert to `year`s.

```
#sample data for testing
np.random.seed(100)
start = pd.to_datetime('1991-02-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=36, freq='A')

df = pd.DataFrame({'cname': ['Albania'] * 18 + ['Argentina'] * 18, 
                   'year': rng.year, 
                    'rgdpna.pop': np.random.choice([0,1,2], size=36)})  
#print (df)

df.year = pd.to_datetime(df.year, format='%Y')
df1 = df.set_index('year').groupby('cname').resample('9A',closed='left').mean().reset_index()
df1.year = df1.year.dt.year
print (df1)
       cname  year  rgdpna.pop
0    Albania  1999    1.000000
1    Albania  2008    1.000000
2  Argentina  2017    0.888889
3  Argentina  2026    0.888889
```

Comment: It is hard for me to implement it because I am a new user. Please justify it fit more as it gives me errors. 
Thank you a lot

Comment: Ok, no problem. Are data confidental?

Comment: No, I will uploaded now

Comment: Sorry, now I am going to bed now. But tommorow I try help you.

Comment: But maybe is necessary only convert file to `dataframe` by `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`

Comment: Ok, can you send your file to my email in my profile?

Comment: yes please. I tried yesterday and I wasn't able to upload it here.

Comment: Ok, so please send me your file.

Comment: I also tried to run the pd.datatime command but it always gives me function not available

Comment: I think there is some typo only.

Comment: yes, I also think so. But how can I contact you ?

Comment: in my profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael?tab=profile is my email ;)

Comment: I sent you an email ;) Thanks a lot for your help :)